# What is the meaning of auto when using C++ trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Instead of usual

```
void foo (void ) {
    cout << "Meaning of life: " << 42 << endl;
}
```

`C++11` allows is an alternative, using the Trailing Return

```
auto bar (void) -> void {
    cout << "More meaning: " << 43 << endl;
}
```

**In the latter - what is `auto` designed to represent?**

Another example, consider function

```
auto func (int i) -> int (*)[10] {

}
```

**Same question, what is the meaning of `auto` in this example?**

Comment: Have to read about this - but my guess nothing - you did not return anything ;-)

Comment: Please reread the question. The return type of course of `void`, in this context what is the meaning of `auto`

Comment: got it the second time missed the ->void

Comment: Which should be used question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, the new keyword `auto` in C++11 indicates that the type of the expression (in this case the return type of a function) should be inferred from the result of the expression, in this case, what occurs after the `->`.

Without it, the function would have no type (thus not being a function), and the compiler would end up confused.

Comment: I believe what follows the `->` signifies the return type, in this example `void`.

Comment: @Jam yes, and it signifies that the return type should be inferred from that expression (mostly used with `decltype`).

Comment: If i say `auto func (int i) -> int (*)[10];`, I am being explicit as to the return type, right? Why is `auto` needed still?

Comment: @Jam: Auto is needed because the syntax of C++ demands a return type there. Without it you wouldn't be defining a function, you'd be calling one.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thank you as well. Reread your answer again and got it. :) Will accept in ~5min

Comment: What follows the `->` is not an expression whose type is used, it has to be a type.  Don't confuse trailing return types with `decltype` (even though they're often used together).

Answer (score 18):

Consider the code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
Tx Add(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    return t1+t2;
}
```

Here the return type depends on expression `t1+t2`, which in turn depends on how `Add` is called. If you call it as:

```
Add(1, 1.4);
```

`T1` would be `int`, and `T2` would be `double`. The resulting **type** is now `double` (int+double). And hence **`Tx`** should (must) be specified using `auto` and `->`

```
 template<typename T1, typename T2>
    auto Add(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1+t2)
    {
        return t1+t2;
    }
```

You can read about it in [my article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71540/Explicating-the-new-C-standard-C-0x-and-its-implem#TrailingReturn).

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is relatively straightforward, and not covered in other answers here.

Basically, without the `auto`, there are ambiguities, so The Committee decided "you need `auto` here to avoid those ambiguities".

```
class A {
    T B;
};

class B;

A* f();

f()->B;
```

Now, what does `f()->B` mean? Is it a function with no parameters that returns a `B` (with trailing return type syntax), or is it a function call to `A* f()`?

If we didn't have the `auto` required at the start of the trailing return type syntax, we wouldn't be able to tell. With the `auto`, it's clear that this is a function call.

So, to avoid the unclearness here, we simply *require* `auto` at the start of any function declaration that uses a trailing return type.