# Strange function syntax: auto (*f3)(int n)->int (*)[n];

Tags: c++

I came across this weird function syntax:

```
const int n = 3;

auto (*f3)(int n)->int (*)[n]; //error: parameter 'n' as array bound
```

while reading about scope at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) at cppreference.com.

Although the second statement is an error, how do you interpret it? (assuming the scope error was rectified)

I think the first part is a pointer to function but its the part from the 
-> onwards thats got me stumped.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: `int (*)[n]` is "pointer to array of `n` `int`".

Comment: You don't understand the syntax or the return type? 1. Trailing return type. 2. T.C told you.

Comment: If it helps you to compare, the way you'd declare this without a trailing return type and without type aliases is `int(*(*f3)(int n1))[n]`.

Comment: Yes. Understand the pre c++11 syntax. This puts it into even clearer perspective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Although the second statement is an error, how do you interpret it? (assuming the scope error was rectified)

Example shows you the difference btw 2 cases:

```
const int n = 3;

int (*(*f2)(int n))[n];
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
const int n = 3;

int (*(*f2)(int n1))[n];
```

while

```
const int n = 3;

auto (*f3)(int n)->int (*)[n];
```

is equivalent to:

```
const int n = 3;

auto (*f3)(int n1)->int (*)[n1];
```

and article exlains why. If you mean fixing this code by:

```
const int n = 3;

auto (*f3)(int n1)->int (*)[n];
```

then it would declare a pointer to function that accept one parameter of type `int` and returns pointer to array of 3 ints.

Comment: I know the statement is wrong. What I dont know is how to interpret the statement. Never seen it before. Trying to use the right left rule to figure out the declaration but cant see the light

Comment: Thank you T.C., black and Slava. So its called auto with trailing return type. I didnt know what it was called so i didnt know what to google for. Found the [relevant page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224325/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-when-using-c-trailing-return-type) on SO as a result.

Answer (score 4):

The `->` syntax with `auto` and trailing return type is new in C++11. You can't directly apply the inside-out declaration interpretation rules to the whole thing, only to the separate parts to the left of `->` and to the right of `->`.

If we get rid of the error

```
const int n = 3;
auto (*f3)(int m) -> int (*)[n];
```

then the proper equivalent "classic" version can be written as

```
const int n = 3;
typedef int (*T)[n];

T (*f3)(int m);
```

i.e. the `int (*)[n]` part is the return type.

In other words

```
T (*f3)(int m);
```

and

```
auto (*f3)(int m) -> T;
```

are the same thing. The `typedef` helps to emphasize the equivalence.

Comment: Thanks AnT. Yeah got it now.