# C++ value is not usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++, unit-testing, initialization, expression, constants

I've written the following code in C++. I must admit that I'm fairly new to the language, but I'm trying my very best to learn :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

enum class Unit { km, m, cm };

template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure {
    static const int value = v;
    static const Unit unit = u;
};


template<typename M1, typename M2>
struct Measures_same {
    static const bool value() {
        return M1::unit == M2::unit;
    }
};

template<typename M1, typename M2>
struct SmallestUnit {
    static const Unit value() {
        switch(M1::unit) {
            case Unit::km:
                return M2::unit;
            case Unit::m:
                switch (M2::unit) {
                    case Unit::km:
                        return M1::unit;
                    case Unit::m:
                        return M2::unit;
                    case Unit::cm:
                        return M2::unit;
                }
            case Unit::cm:
                return M1::unit;
        }
    };
};


template<typename M1, typename M2>
struct Measure_difference {
    static const int value(){
        if(Measures_same<M1,M2>::value()){
            return 0;
        }
        Unit smallestValue = SmallestUnit<M1, M2>::value();
        Unit largestValue;
        if(M1::unit == smallestValue){
            largestValue = M2::unit;
        }
        else{
            largestValue = M1::unit;
        }

        switch(smallestValue) {
            case Unit::m:
                switch (largestValue) {
                    case Unit::km:
                        return 1000;
                }
            case Unit::cm:
                switch (largestValue) {
                    case Unit::km:
                        return 1000 * 1000;
                    case Unit::m:
                        return 1000;
                }
        }
    }
};

template<typename M1, typename M2>
struct Measure_add {
    static const M1 value(){
        if(Measures_same<M1,M2>::value()){
            return Measure<(M1::value + M2::value), M1::unit>();
        }
        Unit smallestValue = SmallestUnit<decltype(M1::unit), decltype(M2::unit)>::value();

        int const difference = Measure_difference<M1,M2>::value();
        if(M1::unit == smallestValue){
            return Measure<(M1::value + (M2::value * difference)), M1::unit>();
        }
        else{
            return Measure<(M2::value + (M1::value * difference)), M2::unit>();
        }
    }
};

void testMeasuresSame(){
    assert((Measures_same<Measure<10,Unit::km>, Measure<10,Unit::km>>::value()) == true);
    assert((Measures_same<Measure<10,Unit::km>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == false);
    assert((Measures_same<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == false);
}

void testSmallestUnit(){
    assert((SmallestUnit<Measure<1, Unit::km>, Measure<2, Unit::km>>::value()) == Unit::km);
    assert((SmallestUnit<Measure<10,Unit::km>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == Unit::m);
    assert((SmallestUnit<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == Unit::cm);
}

void testMeasureDifference(){
    assert((Measure_difference<Measure<1, Unit::km>, Measure<2, Unit::km>>::value()) == 0);
    assert((Measure_difference<Measure<10,Unit::km>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == 1000);
    assert((Measure_difference<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::m>>::value()) == 1000);
    assert((Measure_difference<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::km>>::value()) == 1000 * 1000);
}

void testMeasureAdd(){
    Measure_add<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::cm>>::value();
}

int main() {
    testMeasuresSame();
    testSmallestUnit();
    testMeasureDifference();
    testMeasureAdd();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when running the line `Measure_add<Measure<10,Unit::cm>, Measure<10,Unit::cm>>::value();`, I get the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target unitconverter
[ 95%] Building CXX object H08-unit-converter/CMakeFiles/unitconverter.dir/src/unitconverter.cxx.o
/unitconverter.cxx: In instantiation of ‘static const M1 Measure_add<M1, M2>::value() [with M1 = Measure<10, (Unit)2>; M2 = Measure<10, (Unit)2>]’:
/unitconverter.cxx:112:62:   required from here
/unitconverter.cxx:78:63: error: could not convert ‘Measure<20, (Unit)2>()’ from ‘Measure<20, (Unit)2>’ to ‘const Measure<10, (Unit)2>’
             return Measure<(M1::value + M2::value), M1::unit>();
                                                               ^
/unitconverter.cxx:84:78: error: the value of ‘difference’ is not usable in a constant expression
             return Measure<(M1::value + (M2::value * difference)), M1::unit>();
                                                                              ^
/unitconverter.cxx:82:19: note: ‘difference’ was not initialized with a constant expression
         int const difference = Measure_difference<M1,M2>::value();
                   ^
/unitconverter.cxx:84:78: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
             return Measure<(M1::value + (M2::value * difference)), M1::unit>();
                                                                              ^
/unitconverter.cxx:87:78: error: the value of ‘difference’ is not usable in a constant expression
             return Measure<(M2::value + (M1::value * difference)), M2::unit>();
                                                                              ^
/unitconverter.cxx:82:19: note: ‘difference’ was not initialized with a constant expression
         int const difference = Measure_difference<M1,M2>::value();
                   ^
/unitconverter.cxx:87:78: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
             return Measure<(M2::value + (M1::value * difference)), M2::unit>();
                                                                              ^
```

I would like to return a Measure from the Measure_add trait with the results. I don't really understand why I cannot use difference like this. Moreover, I'm unsure if I am properly returning a Measure trait like this.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The value is part of the type, so when adding `M1` and `M2` the result type cannot be `M1`.

Comment: @BoPersson, thanks for your quick reply. That makes sense, but the return type can also not be Measure, since it is not a class; right?

Comment: I see a problem here, but I don't have a complete solution. If you look at the somewhat similar [`<ratio>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ratio) for rational arithmetic, you will see that it doesn't have a function for addition, but instead produces a new type containing the combined value. Perhaps you can do something along that line.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message carefully:

> /unitconverter.cxx:78:63: error: could not convert `‘Measure<20,
>   (Unit)2>()’` from `‘Measure<20, (Unit)2>’` to `‘const Measure<10,
>   (Unit)2>`’
>                `return Measure<(M1::value + M2::value), M1::unit>();`

The problem occurs in line below (and similar)

```
static const M1 value(){
    if(Measures_same<M1,M2>::value()){
        return Measure<(M1::value + M2::value), M1::unit>();
    }
    ...
```

Both value and unit are template type in your case. When you add `M1::value` and `M2::value`, you are changing (one of) the template parameter and type may not be same as `M1` unless `M2::value` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That makes a lot of sense. However, I cannot make the type "Measure" since it is not a class, nor do I know the value or unit before the actual return, right?

Comment: @user1390504 What version of C++ are you using?  If you have C++14 just use `auto` as the return type.  If you have C++11 you can use a [trailing return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224325/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-when-using-c-trailing-return-type)