# Should the trailing return type syntax be the default syntax for all functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, return-type, function-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alternative function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/alternative-function-syntax)

In complicated function templates, you sometimes need the C++11 trailing return type syntax in order to use `decltype` on parameters, which otherwise would come into scope too late:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(const T& a, const U& b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Wouldn't it be more consistent to *always* use this new syntax from now on, even for normal functions?

```
auto main() -> int;
```

Then we only have to deal with one function syntax instead of two in modern code, and we could deprecate the old syntax, just like we deprecated implicit int or implicit using declarations.

To make the new syntax more attractive, we could replace `auto` with a nicer name:

```
#define def auto
```

And suddenly the signature of `main` looks very attractive to the functional programmer:

```
def main() -> int;
```

Am I overlooking something? Is the trailing return type syntax inferior in some way I haven't thought of?

Comment: You're my favorite question asker, Fred. :-] That being said, no, it's not inferior and this is purely subjective.

Comment: I would personally prefer everyone use the new form, but it's still just too jarring.

Comment: `auto main() -> int` is a lot wordier and noiser than `int main` and it delays the gratification for no good reason. So the answer is "no", Mr PeterJacksonOverflow.