# Why is Visual Studio 2013 having trouble with this class member decltype?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, decltype

```
#include <vector>

struct C
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    decltype(v.begin()) begin() { return v.begin(); }
    decltype(v.end()) end() { return v.end(); }
};
```

Clang++ has no problem, but MSVC 2013 gives the following error:

```
error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235245/103167 for why this coding style is broken in any compiler, and you should use trailing-return type for `decltype` on members of `this`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known bug in VS2013, [fixed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/01/c-compiler-front-end-fixes-in-vs2015/)<sup>†</sup> in VS2015. The compiler will accept the code if you use a trailing return type instead.

```
struct C
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto begin() -> decltype(v.begin()) { return v.begin(); }
    auto end()   -> decltype(v.end())   { return v.end(); }
};
```

As the bug report says, another work around is by using:

```
struct C
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    decltype(std::declval<decltype(v)>().begin()) begin() { return v.begin(); }
    decltype(std::declval<decltype(v)>().end())   end()   { return v.end(); }
};
```

But as @BenVoigt points out in the comments, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235245/103167) for why the trailing return type should be the preferred option.

---

<sup>†</sup> Search the linked page for *C++ decltype of class-member access incompletely implemented*

Comment: What about trailing return type, which the bug report says works fine?  `auto begin() -> decltype(v.begin()) { return v.begin(); }`  Seems much nicer to me, if it works right

Comment: @BenVoigt Agreed, updated the answer. And thanks for linking to that answer by litb, I wasn't aware of that limitation.

Comment: The link is helpfully dead, but it is [mentioned as being fixed in VS2015 here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/01/c-compiler-front-end-fixes-in-vs2015/).

Comment: @Timmmm Thanks for the link, I've updated the answer and removed the old link. MS decided to shutdown connect and as usual left no redirect, breaking all those links.