# Is there an intention behind the auto keyword in trailing return type function syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, function-declaration, trailing-return-type

In C++11, the two lines are equivalent. From what I see, the the [advantage of the second syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11215227/1079110) is that the return type is in class scope. Therefore, you can use both, nested types of the class directly and `decltype` expressions of non static members. Moreover, the function names line up nicely.

```
int foo(int bar);
auto foo(int bar) -> int;
```

The `auto` keyword is used here, which can also be used to automatically derive the type of local variables. However, I don't see the analogy here. In the function declaration syntax, nothing is derived. The return type is mentioned explicitly behind the arrow.

Personally, I would say that the syntax would be clearer without the `auto` keyword. Is there any intention behind this? Which?

Comment: Language designers were constrained in their choice of keywords. Even the use of the `auto` in deriving the type automatically is a re-purposing of the `auto` keyword, which was there since K&R's version of C, where it meant something completely different®.

Comment: not only class scope, `auto foo(int i, int j) -> decltype(i+j)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think you don't need a keyword here at all. Old function syntax has no keyword neither.

Comment: C++ reuses keywords to mean different things in different cases... `typename` and `static` for example. I agree this is bad :)

Comment: @Dave: `auto int i = 1;` is no longer a valid syntax in C++11

Comment: @Dave Out of interest, what's the second use case of `typename`? I only know it as alternative to `class` for template arguments.

Comment: @danijar: dependent names, like `typename T::iterator`, where `T` is a template argument

Comment: Old function syntax starts with a type.  Types involve type modifiers (like cv or the like) and types that where named before.  Parser simply has to say "a type, or `auto`" starts a declaration now, instead of "a type".  The exact details of why `auto` was required would probably require delving into the discussions made when the feature was added on standard mailing lists and newsgroups, and/or looking at a few compiler implementations...

Comment: What @Yakk says (me too).

Comment: [N1978](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2006/n1978.pdf) "If the return type expression comes before the argument list, parsing becomes difficult and name lookup may be less intuitive; the argument names may have other uses in an outer scope at the site of the function declaration. We suggest reusing the `auto` keyword to express that the return type is to follow after the argument list." There's also a reference to *Bjarne Stroustrup. Draft proposal for "typeof". C++ reflector message c++std-ext-5364, October 2002.*, but I'm not sure if that's public.

Comment: @dyp Thanks, could you turn that into a short answer, please?

Comment: In the past (in C at least), if you left off the return type from in front of a function it would default to `int`. Perhaps putting `auto` in front will allow older parsers to still assume that no return type implies `int`.

Comment: @YoungJohn Interesting idea, however as far as I know default-int is not supported in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper ["Decltype (revision 5)", N1978](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2006/n1978.pdf) proposed the syntax for *trailing-return-type* (as they're now known). This was done to simplify defining function templates whose return type depends on an expression involving its arguments in chapter 3:

> ```
> template <class T, class U> decltype((*(T*)0)+(*(U*)0)) add(T t, U u);
> ```
>
> The expression `(*(T*)0)` is a hackish way to write an expression that has the type `T` and does not require `T` to be default
>   constructible. If the argument names were in scope, the above
>   declaration could be written as:
>
> ```
> template <class T, class U> decltype(t+u) add(T t, U u);
> ```
>
> Several syntaxes that move the return type expression after the
>   argument list are discussed in [Str02]. If the return type expression
>   comes before the argument list, parsing becomes difficult and name
>   lookup may be less intuitive; the argument names may have other uses
>   in an outer scope at the site of the function declaration.
>
> We suggest reusing the `auto` keyword to express that the return type
>   is to follow after the argument list. The return type expression is
>   preceded by `->` symbol, and comes after the argument list and
>   potential cv-qualifiers in member functions and the exception
>   specification:
>
> ```
> template <class T, class U> auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);
> ```

The reference [Str02] is *"Bjarne Stroustrup. Draft proposal for "typeof". C++ reflector message c++std-ext-5364, October 2002."*, but I'm not sure if that's publicly available.

Comment: Please add examples of potential parsing difficulties, if you know any.

Comment: I think that the parsing difficulties are akin to the "most vexing parse." Without the 'auto', how would the compiler know whether `f(T(t), U(t),` is the start of a call to f or of a declaration of f? The compiler only finds out when it encounters the "->" or the ";". There could be a very long list of very complex argument types before that, requiring unlimited look-ahead. Compiler builders don't like those parsing problems, especially if they are avoided by requiring a simple keyword at the start of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer to complement @dyp's excellent answer.

Here's a real-world example from some code in my project that would be very difficult to write without the trailing return type:

```
    template<class F, class... ArgTypes>
    auto expected_from_code(F&& f, ArgTypes&& ...args)
    -> expected_t<
    typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_void<decltype(f(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))>::value,
    decltype(f(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))>::type>
    {
        using expected = expected_t<decltype(f(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))>;
        try {
            return expected { f(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...) };
        }
        catch(...) {
            return expected { typename expected::exception_sentinel{} };
        }
    }
```

Comment: the question isn't asking why should there be a trailing return type, it is asking why a function with a trailing return type needs to have the 'auto' keyword in front.

Comment: While I think it complements the existing answer, I agree with @YoungJohn. It might fit [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr) better.