# Most Efficient way to search if a string contain all numbers from 0 to 9 at least once?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

```
bool IsWin(string A, string B)
{
    vector<int> vec = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for(long int i=0;i<A.length();i++){
        vec[A[i]-'0'] = 11;
    }

    if(IsArray(vec)){    //IsArray(vec) It just checks whether all elements are 11.
        return true;
    }

    for(long int i=0;i<B.length();i++){
        vec[B[i]-'0'] = 11;
    }

    return IsArray(Array);
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Till Now I've just come up with this solution. But this isn't efficient as required.

Comment: If you have a solution that works, but you're looking for a more efficient way, you could try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bhavayanand Define _efficient_ please. Percormance wise, memory wise, less code?

Comment: @TheDude add "readable" to that list.

Comment: performance wise @TheDude

Comment: Will sure do @AtesGoral Thanks

Comment: @bhavayanand Use a profiler then to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what a bottleneck is? @TheDude

Comment: Bottleneck is the point at which the program is most slow, either because it has to do a lot of work (may or may not be necessary), sits around waiting, or is just plain slow. The necessary is unavoidable, look for a better algorithm, the unnecessary you prune out and carry on.

Comment: Thank You so much for the explanation @user4581301

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the obvious way would be something like this:

```
bool has_all_digits(std::string const &input) { 
    std::vector<char> present(10, 0);
    for (auto c : input)
        present[c - '0' ] = 1;

    return std::find(present.begin(), present.end(), 0) == present.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code a little? I'm new to programming.

Comment: What is return and find function doing in this code?

Comment: @bhavayanand http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find you can inform yourself about that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is probably the most efficient way to solve this.

```
bool check(string s){
    std::bitset<10> digits;
    int digitCounter = 0;
    int index;

    for (char c : s){
        if (std::isdigit(c)){
            index = c - '0';

            if (!digits[index]){
                digitCounter++;
                digits[index] = true;

                if (digitCounter == 10)
                    return true;
            }       
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still not efficient enough. 16 out of 19 submissions get timed out.

Comment: Try now. And if it's not enough I'd like to see the subsmissions sampler.

Comment: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hackerrank-hiring-contest/challenges/winning-lottery-ticket/)

Answer (score 0):

This will have out of range exceptions for vec if A or B contains anything beside digits.
Between the loops vec needs to be reinitialised.
Further the last line should be `IsArray(vec)`.
And why not use a `vector<bool> vec`?

Before you care for efficiency the algorithm should work and be exception safe.

Comment: It's a competitive programming question. so vector will never get any input other than digits according to the constraints given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Any talk about performance is meaningless without benchmarking. So you need to measure and then measure some more.

With that in mind here is a version that is optimized for long strings with dense digits, i.e. that have a high probability to contain all the digits in a small substring. The function will exits as soon as it found all the digits and will not continue to the rest of the string:

```
auto has_all_digits(const std::string& str) -> bool
{
    std::array<int, 10> digits = {};
    int num_digits = 0;

    for (char ch : str)
    {
        if (!is_digit(ch))
            continue;

        // here is a cool branchless trick
        // to count unique digits

        int x = 1;
        std::swap(digits[ch - '0'], x); // put 1 to digits and get the old value in x
        num_digits += 1 - x; // increment if the old value was 0

        if (num_digits == 10)
            return true;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

Again, don't forget to measure and see if this algorithm is indeed eficient for your use case.

Comment: In std::swap function you swap the value of x with some uninitialised digits[ ] element. Wouldn't x will get some garbage value? If this is some stupid or obvious ques please forgive me i'm new to programming.

Comment: @bhavayanand `digits` is initialized. See the `= {}`

Comment: But there's no value in braces. Does this mean all value to be initialised to 0 or NULL ?

Comment: @bhavayanand `0` in this case. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Okay I got it now. From your ans i got to know about auto , range based for loop, array default constructor , that i didn't know before. Just one last thing, in first line, -> bool what does this mean??

Comment: @bhavayanand see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr