# C++ auto function return?

Tags: c++

lately I've seen some code with functions labeled like this:

```
auto Function(...) -> BOOL
```

Is there some difference between using just

```
BOOL Function(...)
```

The first one looks nicer to me though, maybe I'm just weird, so is it just visual, or it has some other benefits?

Comment: It's called *trailing return type* an can be very useful if the returned type depends on the arguments to your function. Otherwise they are just the same the way you show it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: I'm with you stylistically. It makes all the functions align nicely to the start of the line, without messing with spaceing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some difference between using just [...]

No - in your particular example, they are equivalent.

---

> it just visual, or it has some other benefits?

Trailing return types have a few benefits:

- Easier to switch to *automatic return type deduction* in the future (just delete everything after `->`)
- Can use parameters as part of the return type
- Can access class `C` type aliases without having to say `C::`

In your particular example, these do not apply.

Comment: Read also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr) and 
  this [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html). It can be very useful with lambda and decltype, sizeof

Comment: Not sure if deleting everything after the `->` is really easier than changing the return type from `BOOL` to `auto`.

Answer (score 7):

The statement `auto Function(...) -> some_type` is used when you need type deduction of the arguments before the return type

```
template<class T>
   decltype(a*b) add(T a, T b){
   return a + b;
}
```

But this wont work so you need:

```
 template<class T>
   auto add(T a, T b) -> decltype(a + b) {
   return a + b;
 }
```

Comment: `bool` is clearly not dependent upon the parameters.

Comment: Because you answer is false. It is used for type deduction of the return type based on the arguments. And usually that's only relevant in meta programming.

The bool versions as shown in the question make no difference at all.

Comment: And your code in invalid as well, as it doesn't really show the trailing return type.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I was implying that type deduction (i.e. return type) is based on the arguments. I hope my example is now clearer

Comment: Thank you all guys, didn't really expect that much heat there lol

Comment: It is "heat" only for sake of clarity, accuracy, and posterity.  It is not intended as an insult, although sometimes it may appear to be a dogpile.

Comment: @Eljay Couldn't agree more!