# why this strange syntax of function in c++ is works?

Tags: c++

**what is this syntax item in C++ and for what it use?**

I've just come across this strange C++ syntax:

```
auto someFunc() -> int{
    int a = 42;
    return a;
}
```

i cant find in google what is it, so i try ask it here.
thanks for answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should the trailing return type syntax style become the default for new C++11 programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr)

Comment: Your modern C++ book should cover this.

Comment: Note: This is C++ syntax and has *absolutely nothing* to do with C. There is no such thing as C/C++.