# C++ Variadic Templates for a General-Purpose and Fast Data Storage Container Builder

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, std

```
template< typename ... Args>
auto build_array(Args&&... args) -> std::array<typename std::common_
type<Args...>::type, sizeof...(args)>
{
    using commonType = typename std::common_type<Args...>::type;
    return {std::forward<commonType>(args)...};
}

int main()
{
    auto data = build_array(1, 0u, 'a', 3.2f, false);
    for(auto i: data)
    std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Hey guys, I cannot understand the above code. So basically, the code is to write a function that takes any number of elements of any type, which can, in turn, be converted into a common type. The function should also return a container having all the elements converted into that common type, and it should also be fast to traverse. This is a books solution.

From what I understand `<typename... Args>` is to allow a variation of parameters. Then, `(Args&&...args)` also allows for a variety of parameters, but only rvalues? I do not understand the arrow notation and the rest of the function declaration. Like what is the difference between each of them. Additionally, the book also passes in ? for the templates such as, `std::array<?,?>`?

Finally, what does the return statement even mean (ending with an ellipsis?) ? and forward?
Sorry, I am rambling on, but I just cannot make sense and obtain a detailed overview of what is going on.
It would be really kind of you if you can elaborate on this?

Comment: The arrow notation is called **trailing return type**. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215227/should-the-trailing-return-type-syntax-style-become-the-default-for-new-c11-pr) for example. So your function's return type is `std::array<typename std::common_
type<Args...>::type, sizeof...(args)>`

Comment: `Args&&` is a *forwarding reference* that can bind lvalues or rvalues.

Answer (score 2):

> but only rvalues?

When you see `T&&`,

- if `T` is ***not*** a template parameter, then `T&&` means an rvalue reference to `T`, which can bind to rvalules only;
- if `T` is a template parameter, then `T&&` means a forwarding/universal reference to `T`, which can bind to both rvalue and lvalues.

Therefore, in your case, since `Args` is a template parameter (precisely a *type template parameter pack*, number (2) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)), `Args&&... args` expands to a comma separated sequence of function parameter declarations each of which has type a forwarding reference. For instance, if you pass 3 arguments to `build_array`, the deduction takes place as if you had a declaration like this:

```cpp
template<typename Arg1, typname Arg2, typname Arg3>
auto build_array(Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2, Arg3&& arg3)
    -> std::array<typename std::common_type<Arg1, Arg2, Arg3>::type, 3>
```

> what does the return statement even mean (ending with an ellipsis?) ?

Again, `...` is to expand some variadic thing in a comma separated sequence of things. So if `args` in

```cpp
return {std::forward<commonType>(args)...};
```

is actually 3 things, then that statement is expanded to

```cpp
return {std::forward<commonType>(arg1), std::forward<commonType>(arg2), std::forward<commonType>(arg3)};
```

Notice the position of the ellipsis. `f(args)...` is expanded to `f(arg1), f(arg2), f(arg3), …`, whereas `f(args...)` would be expanded to `f(arg1, arg2, arg3, …)`.

> and forward?

That's probably the less easy to understand bit, and would require a dedicated question. However ***many*** questions on that topic exist already, so you just have to search for them, rather than asking a new one. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65446786/5825294) an answer of mine where I've most clearly explained the difference between `std::move` and `std::forward`. If you set understanding that answer of mine as your target, you'll understand `std::forward` (and `std::move`) and everything will be clearer.

> I do not understand the arrow notation and the rest of the function declaration.

Essentially,

```cpp
auto f(/* parameters */) -> SomeType
```

is equivalent to

```cpp
SomeType f(/* parameters */)
```

with the advantage that in the former `SomeType` can refer to types that are in `/* parameters */`, if needed. In your case the return type makes use of `Args`.

> the book also passes in `?` for the templates such as, `std::array<?,?>`?

Probably the book is just trying to guide you through argument deduction, and it's using `?` to mean "we don't know yet what it is; keep reading".